# How to avoid Nginx multiple responses

Tags: nginx

Consider a similar HTTP request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NonExistent Client
Content-Length: 4

foo=bar
```

As you can see, the request is invalid, eg. the payload length is 7 bytes, but CL header contains only 4.

Nginx gives two responses for this request:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 03 Mar 2023 20:55:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 146
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 03 Mar 2023 20:55:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The first response contains the "normal" 404, that's what I expected.

The second response is because the server continues the processing of the request - which is a totally wrong request, and it gives the 400.

The server writes a log entry:

```
2023/03/03 20:55:02 [info] 27273#27273: *8 client sent invalid method while reading client pipelined request line, client: 192.168.72.2, server: _, request: "bar"
```

This is why I think that it continues to process the chunked request.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior, namely suppress the second response?

Comment: Small technicality: that's not really a "chunked" request.  Normally "chunked" refers to using the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, which is mutually exclusive with using a `Content-Length` header.  As nginx's log message implies, it believes it is handling a "pipelined" request.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could prevent this is to set [`keepalive_requests 1;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_requests) in your nginx configuration.

This will cause it to always hang up after processing the first request, but that is likely to have a negative impact on performance for well-behaved clients.

In theory it seems possible to disable `keep-alive` only for specific user agents, but [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/975539/keepalive-disable-parameters-nginx-for-particular-useragent-browsers) suggests that nginx doesn't support that.  You also can apparently not put `keepalive_requests` inside an `if ($http_user_agent ~ NonExistent) {}` block.

Aside from that, seems like your best bet would be to fix the broken client.  If you can't get it to send the correct `Content-Length`, maybe you could configure it to not request `keep-alive`?

Comment: Thanks for responses - this topic was a bit old, meanwhile I contacted with Nginx and ModSecurity developers, and we successfully resolved the problem. The vendor opened a CVE: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-28882